# Eclipse XSLT output HTML file format

Tags: html, xml, eclipse, xslt

I did XSL transformation in eclipse and the html output from transformation is not formated like every html file which I added manualy in to eclipse. Does anybody know where is the problem?

[image: XSL transformation]

[image: output HTML file]

Comment: I guess you need to explain what exactly you want to achieve and in which way the result is not what you want. Consider to edit your question as well to include minimal but complete code snippets allowing others to reproduce the problem instead on relying on screenshoots.

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have opened the HTML using the plain text editor.

Right click on the file in Package Explorer and choose 'Open With > HTML Editor'.

Eclipse remembers which editor you used for a file so you should only have to do this once.

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake. I have opened with "Text editor". Thank You